# NodeJs Error When Submitting Email using Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I have followed these steps to setup nodemailer
1) Allow access to less secure apps in gmail
2) Written the following in app.js

```
app.post('/reachus/send',function(req,res){
var transporter=nodemailer.createTransport({
    service:'Gmail',
    auth: {
        user:'my@gmail.com',
        pass:'***'
    }
});

var mailOptions={
    from:'Naveen DK <my@gmail.com>',
    to:'my@gmail.com',
    subject:'Email Sent from your website',
    text:'You have a submission with the following details.. Name: '+req.body.name +'Email: '+req.body.email+' Message: '+ req.body.message,
    html:   '<p>You have a submission with the following details..</p><ul><li> Name :'+req.body.name + ' </li><li>Email: '+req.body.email +'</li><li>Message ' + req.body.message +'</li></ul>'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,function(error,info){
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
        res.redirect('/');
    } else{
        console.log('Message Sent ' + info.response);
        res.redirect('/');
    }
  });
});
```

3) Once I Click on Submit Email I get the following error

```
 { Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:569:26)
    code: 'ECONNECTION',
    errno: 'ECONNRESET',
    syscall: 'read',
    command: 'CONN
 }
```

Please find the below 2 vids for more details

1 https://www.dropbox.com/s/nc1zvivlfpabj6h/HowMyCodeLooksLike.wmv?dl=0

2 https://www.dropbox.com/s/tfsqu6ir90s682h/ErrorOnceSubmissionDone.wmv?dl=0

Thanks in advance

Naveen

Comment: you have not pass "host" in createTrasport

Comment: I have tried the following:

Method one -passing the host
----------------
app.post('/reachus/send',function(req,res){
var transporter=nodemailer.createTransport({
    pool:true,
    host:'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:465,
    secure:true,
    auth: {
        user:'',
        pass:''
    }
});
----------------

Tried by adding nodemailer-smtp-transport'
----------
app.post('/reachus/send',function(req,res){
    var  transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    service:'gmail',
    auth: {
        user:'',
        pass:''
    }
   
})); ----But no luck

Comment: it resolved your problem??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use below code for sending email from nodemailer, inside function pass ur parameter and you will get ur result.

```
var AppConfig = {
'sendEmailID': 'useremail',
'sendEmailFromName': 'senderemail',
'sendEmailPassword': 'password'
```

}

```
function SendEmail(toEmail, Subject, html) {
// create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport 
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: '587',
    auth: {
        user: "username",
        pass: AppConfig.sendEmailPassword
    },
    secureConnection: 'false',
    tls: {
        ciphers: 'SSLv3'
    }

});

// setup e-mail data with unicode symbols 
var mailOptions = {
    from: AppConfig.sendEmailFromName, // sender address 
    to: toEmail, // list of receivers 
    subject: Subject, // Subject line 
    html: html // html body 
};

// send mail with defined transport object 
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
    if (error) {
        return console.log("ERROR----" + error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
});
```

}

Answer (score 2):

With the response I got from @chetan mekha I changed my code as follows:

```
var  smtpTransport=nodemailer.createTransport({
   host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: '587',
    auth: {
        user: "**",
        pass: "**"
    },
    secureConnection: 'false',
    tls: {
        ciphers: 'SSLv3'

    }
});
```

But there another error came up saying : { [Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain] code: 'ECONNECTION', command: 'CONN' } But adding the line 
rejectUnauthorized: false under ciphers made it work! so final code snippet that worked for me looks like this..

```
var  smtpTransport=nodemailer.createTransport({
   host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: '587',
    auth: {
        user: "**",
        pass: "**"
    },
    secureConnection: 'false',
    tls: {
        ciphers: 'SSLv3',
        rejectUnauthorized: false

    }
});
```