# Nodemailer ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am trying to use `nodemailer` to send an email but I keep getting this error:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
...

app.post('/api/SendEmail', (req, res) => {
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        auth: {
            user: 'x@gmail.com',
            pass: 'x'
        }
    });

    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'x@gmail.com',
        to: 'x@incasu.co.za',
        subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
        text: 'That was easy!'
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, info) {
        if (err) return res.status(400).send(err);
        return res.status(200).send({response: 'success'});
    });
})
```

Could someone please help me with this. I basically followed this process: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_email.asp

**UPDATE:**

I added `service: 'gmail',` in the `transporter` as suggested by `Janith Kasun`:

```
service: 'gmail',
auth: {
    user: 'x@gmail.com',
    pass: 'x'
}
```

My error now changed to this:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Freddy, Have you configured this on gmail?

Comment: I have not. But I have tried other non-gmail emails (like an outlook email) and I still get exactly the same error message

Comment: Oh then you have to do lots of things

Comment: The w3school tutorial I linked doesn't say you need to do more stuff. Could you help me out with what I need to do please?

Comment: Sure please see my edited answer, and post a comment if you need any help

Comment: Hii Freddy please change your password if it's what posted here

Comment: No the "x" in the password and email mean nothing :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182027/discussion-between-janith-kasun-and-freddy-bonda).

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer:

[NodeJs Error When Submitting Email using Nodemailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45707235/nodejs-error-when-submitting-email-using-nodemailer/45710189)

I have no idea what any of these settings do, but my emails are now being sent correctly with this code:

```
var  transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
   host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: '587',
    auth: {
        user: "**",
        pass: "**"
    },
    secureConnection: 'false',
    tls: {
        ciphers: 'SSLv3',
        rejectUnauthorized: false

    }
});
```